# Enable PHP7 apache module - apache 2.4 - Linux Ubuntu 14

Tags: apache, php-7.1

I have problem to use PHP 7.1 with apache.
I installed PHP 7.1:

```
apt-get install php7.1
```

I installed the PHP 7.1 apache module :

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.1
```

I disabled the PHP5 module :

```
sudo a2dismod php5
```

I enabled the PHP7 module :

```
sudo a2enmod php7.1
```

I restarted apache :

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

When I check the apache loaded modules I see the PHP7 module :

```
apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES    >     php7_module (shared)
```

But when I make phpinfo() it is always PHP5 module.
Any idea ?
Thanks.

Comment: Modify your httpd.conf, to load PHP7 and not PHP5.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I use Apache 2.4 so there is no httpd.conf but an apache2.conf file. Unfortunately I didn't find any "load PHP" directive in this file.
I finished by remove PHP5 to fix the problem ...

Comment: Do you still want to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my experience of installing **PHP 7.3.3** on **Httpd 2.4.33** in Linux environment.

1. When you run the configure command for installing PHP, ensure that apxs is also included.

`--with-apxs2=/path/httpd/bin/apxs`

2. Once you install PHP, you can see that a module **libphp7.so** is installed in httpd/modules.
3. In httpd.conf, add an entry `LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so`
4. Restart Apache.